# Expression type "(_, _) -> Void" is ambiguous without more context

Tags: swift, sdwebimage

Please help me in below code. I'm getting an error:

> Expression type "(_, _) -> Void" is ambiguous without more context.

```
import UIKit
import SDWebImage

class CustomImageView: UIImageView {
    let progressIndicatorView = CircularLoaderView(frame: CGRect.zero)

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!

        addSubview(self.progressIndicatorView)
        progressIndicatorView.frame = bounds
        progressIndicatorView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

        let url = NSURL(string: "http://png-3.findicons.com/files/icons/2795/office_2013_hd/2000/word.png")
        self.sd_setImage(with: url as URL?, placeholderImage: nil, options: .cacheMemoryOnly, progress: { [weak self] (receivedSize, expectedSize) -> Void in
            self.progressIndicatorView.progress = CGFloat(receivedSize)/CGFloat(expectedSize)
        }) { [weak self](image, error, _, _) -> Void in
            self.progressIndicatorView.reveal()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When asking questions about compile-time errors, you need to specify on which line the error occurs. It’s not always obvious and forces others to waste time trying to figure that out.

Comment: Looking at `SDWebImage` implementation, doesn't the `progress` block declare an `URL` as the third parameter?

Comment: What does the signature for `sd_setImage` look like?

Comment: Im getting compile error at:                                                self.sd_setImage(with: url as URL?, placeholderImage: nil, options: .cacheMemoryOnly, progress: { [weak self] (receivedSize, expectedSize) -> Void in @Joshua Nozzi

Answer (score 1):

Change `NSURL` to `URL` should work!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's referring to the `[weak self] (receivedSize, expectedSize) -> Void in`, which means the function `sd.setImage()` has more than one `progress` argument type.

You can probably solve this by explicitly describing the types of `receivedSize` and `expectedSize`, as something like `[weak self] (receivedSize: Type1, expectedSize: Type2) -> Void in`.

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are missing one more parameter from the progressBlock. Check This

```
import UIKit
```

import SDWebImage

class CustomImageView: UIImageView {
    let progressIndicatorView = CircularLoaderView(frame: CGRect.zero)

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!

    addSubview(self.progressIndicatorView)
    progressIndicatorView.frame = bounds
    progressIndicatorView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

    let url = URL(string: "http://png-3.findicons.com/files/icons/2795/office_2013_hd/2000/word.png")!
    self.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage: nil, options: .cacheMemoryOnly, progress: { (receivedSize, expectedSize, _) in
        self.progressIndicatorView.progress = CGFloat(receivedSize)/CGFloat(expectedSize)
    }) { (image, error, _, _) in

    }
}

}
```

Seee there should be three of them in progressBlock

Comment: This answer should work, the code in question missed one parameter in SDWebImageDownloaderProgressBlock.

self.sd_setImage(with: url as URL?, placeholderImage: nil, options: .cacheMemoryOnly, progress: { [weak self] (receivedSize, expectedSize, ______) -> Void in